# How to make the received data appear as HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a textarea with a v-model named content. If I input some text there, it will be assigned to content.description. Now, I want to pass this to another element, namely to a div, but - here comes the tricky part - if my textarea contains some html-code, I want this html code to be interpreted as an html-code and not as a text.

For example, if I input

```
<a href="foo">Some link </a>
```

and I pass it to the div, I want it to be rendered as a clickable link, like

[some link](https://somelink)

and not as

```
<a href="foo">Some link </a>
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Vue `v-html` directive to insert Html in div.

**Working example:**

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        html: '<a href="foo">Some link </a>'
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<textarea v-model="html"></textarea>
<div v-html="html"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: and that's what's strange - it doesn't work! Still receive  <a href="foo">Some link </a> as a result :(

Comment: do you think it may have something to do with the fact that textareas can only pass plain text?

Comment: No I don't think, could you create a codesandbox for this.

Comment: It's strange, with an input it works perfectly well but not with a textarea...so I guess the problem was in the textarea, thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: I have added the working example. Please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

We have to use `v-html` directive inorder to work. Take a look at the documentation [Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html), check the working snippet.

```js
var app6 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-6',
  data: {
    message: '<a href="google.com">Hello Vue!</a>'
  }
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  display:none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.12/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app-6">
  <p v-html="message"></p>
  <textarea v-model="message"></textarea>
</div>
```